# MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException calling a Rest method with curl

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, curl

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.0.6.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR with a restful architecture

```
@PutMapping(path = "/users/alarms2", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public void setAlerts2(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authHeader,
            @RequestBody AlertConfiguration alertConfiguration)

            throws DataAccessException, ClientProtocolException, SQLException, IOException {
..
}
```

but when I call this method from curl:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJyaWNhcmQub2SAsZUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE2MDAxODMzNDAsImlhdCI6MTUzOTcwMzM0MH0.2gbyyGnkcoHjOw7HbUBBQgb59Bw8iAyFbqTe2DPUlOA-V5UwrW3KXWHZlXssZni8oRJ_o1QRzAFtAWMfz7f0Yw" -d ‘{“symbol": “MENU”,  "alarmKey”:”VEGAN” , "enabled": "true"}' "http://95.90.225.68:1133/restos/api/v1/users/alarms2"
```

I got this error in the server:

```
2018-10-17 17:16  [http-nio-1133-exec-9] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(140) - Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "alarms2"]
```

Comment: I don't get it,  your curl should not be PUT instead of GET? curl -X PUT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have another method with a more general signature that overlaps given one. Something like:

```
@PutMapping(path = "/users/{userId}", ...)
public void someMethod(@PathVariable(value = "userId") Long userId) {
...
}
```

So when you consume `/api/v1/users/alarms2` Spring first tries to convert "alarms2" (which is obviously **not** a valid `Long`) to `userId` (which is `Long`)